# How to use the iPhone connect to server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. I am writing an iPhone program which can connect to a server. However, I have not ideas which library of functions should I use in order to develop this program. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve once you connect to the server?
Do you just want to display a web page? If so then read up on `UIWebView`

Do you want to connect to your own back-end server and that supplies data to you client application on the iPhone? If so you should read up on the `NSURLConnection` class.

Read up the iphone documentation for [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) and UIWebView [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actually, I want to connect to the CardDav and CalDav server and download some address book and calendar information to my app. Is it also user the NSURLConnect to achieve this part? Thank you.

Comment: Caldav and CardDav are simply xml data returned by the servers based in http, so yes you should be able to download, parse the data and use it for whatever you need to do

Comment: Do you know how to connect to a server on a different port?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if you want to get the text from the server you can use following method
`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:http://iphonedevbook.com/more/10/text.txt]; 
    textView.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`

actually there are other two ways to get the data from server
Synchronously
ASynchronously

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can I set the type of the server? As I want to connect the CalDav and CardDav server in order to get the address book and calendar data. Is it also possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

yes,there is way to connect server.you can use the following method

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservic/tempconvert.asmx"];`

Regards
Karthikeyan g

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I still have some problems about the statement. After I set the URL (like the above). What can I call the server?